# Наследование в С++

Tags: visual-c++, c++

Как починить код, чтобы можно было вызывать конструктор C(A)? Или совсем отказаться от конструктора в C?

```
class A{

};

class B{
    A &a;
    B(A &na) : a(na){}
};

class C : public B{
    C(A &na){  }

};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
class C : public B {
public:
    C(A &na) : B(na) {}
};
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/gtLaEc

Отказаться от конструктора в `C` не так просто: у `B` есть лишь конструктор, требующий ссылку на `A`, а значит, его надо как-то вызвать.